# Error when using Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I am getting a manish.tiw.android.example.activitywrapper cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl Runtime exception when trying to use a Broadcast receiver to listen to change in Network connectivity status. Can you help me with this?
Stacktrace is -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.amazonaws.cognito.sync.demo.NetworkChangeReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: manish.tiw.android.example.activitywrapper cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2452)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show onReceive method code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution for your problem from github blog that ,Instead of registering the receiver in my Android manifest.xml file, declare and register it in the custom Application class. That solved the problem .